# How to format XMLtext in django template

Tags: python, xml, django, django-templates

I have xml stored in a database field. It is valid XML, but when it is rendered in the template, it looks like this:

[image]

Is there a tool that can format the data to be readable? It should appear something like:

```
<item>
    <ISOLanguage>Hello</ISOLanguage>
    <Something></Something>
<item>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If formatting the source of the XML matters then I'm guessing you could probably use this...

```
import xml.dom.minidom

xml = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(xml_string)
pretty_xml_as_string = xml.toprettyxml()
```

And then send 'pretty_xml_as_string' to the template via context.

'xml_string' is the xml that is stored in your database field.  I'm assuming it's a string, if not, it will need to be converted to a string.

I haven't tested the above but it should be very close to what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the best way to do this would be to use the preformatted html tag, `<pre>`. The following format a string exactly as-is:

```
<pre>{{ localized_item.feed_raw }}</pre>
```